# Is there a shortcut in GRASS for importing vector files?

Tags: grass-gis, vector

Is there a keyboard or command shortcut in GRASS for importing vector files? If you know link where I can find maybe whole list of shortcuts for GRASS, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

v.in.ogr

More info here: http://grass.osgeo.org/grass64/manuals/html64_user/v.in.ogr.html

Here is an example (from the above link) for importing a shapefile:

```
v.in.ogr dsn=/home/user/shape_data layer=test_shape output=grass_map
```

The GRASS commands are listed in the online manuals here: http://grass.osgeo.org/gdp/manuals.php

You can also use the gui tools through Quantum GIS or by doing the command without any parameters (v.in.ogr). I've found it useful to play with all of the parameters within the GRASS gui and watch as the parameters are filled in.

Answer (score 5):

The graphical user interface also support bulk import:

http://grass.osgeo.org/wiki/WxGUI#Import_vector_data

You may like this [video about importing multiple shapefiles](http://gama.fsv.cvut.cz/~landa/grass/swf/import-shp-dir.html)